# Does MySQL support table inheritance?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, inheritance

I have this code in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE first (
  id serial,
  primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE second (primary key(id)) INHERITS (first);
```

What is the equivalent code for MySQL?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have inheritance like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL does not support table inheritance. The only way to approximate the functionality is by using a foreign key (which MySQL isn't too good at either):

```
CREATE TABLE first (
  id serial,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE second (
  parent integer REFERENCES first,
  PRIMARY KEY (parent)
);
```

Obviously, you'd have to change any views and queries from the PostgreSQL "inheritance version" to regular multi-relation queries.

Comment: is there a specific reason(like performance related) that MySQL not supporting it?

Comment: @sajadkk I am not aware of performance issues with inheritance, but it is a relatively new concept and still having some implementation shortcomings. PostgreSQL inheritance is not SQL-compliant, for instance, and not all constraints are inherited so one should be really careful when working with inheritance. (MySQL, incidentally, is far less SQL-standard compliant than PostgreSQL, although I haven't checked improvements lately.) Unless you *really* need inheritance for some data model reason you are probably better off with a standard relational structure.

Comment: "*but it is a relatively new concept*" - that is actually not true. Object relational concepts go way back into the 80's

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "Relatively new concept" as in compared to the relational data model. "Underdeveloped" might be another subjective qualifier, seeing that table inheritance still has some issues with general use (such as constraint enforcement) that have persisted over multiple PG major version releases while other features did have improvements or overhaul.