# Mysql organisation tables

Tags: mysql

I am developing a management system for private lesson.
I need to store information for the student and for their parents.

The parent's information are: full name, address, email, telephone number.
For the student: full name, email

The problem is, in case of adult student all the information between "parents" and "students" are the same.

Moreover, the parents and students have their own user and password (I am going to use the multi auth with laravel).

How can I organise the tables in order to include all the two cases (parent with child/children and adult student)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a Person table. Store all the common info there (including password).

Comment: You mean: a parent table with (full name, email, password), a student table with the same column and a table with all the other details?

Comment: Nope. A person table with all the fields and a PersonId. Then your Student table and Parent table can use this PersonId. This way a person can be both a student and a parent. So there wont be email or password in student or parent tables

Comment: In Postgres there is a inheritance property for this kind of things. However you may do that with foreign keys in MySQL. As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624138/does-mysql-support-table-inheritance